# Chain SQL commands immediately after creating table w/ node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to construct a statement that performs the following without returning a runtime error:

```
data = new sqlite3.Database('data/table.db')
data.run('CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS table(count integer primary key,unit)');
data.run('INSERT INTO table(count,unit) VALUES(0,"oz")')
```

When run consecutively, I receive a

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: table
at Error (native)
```

and obviously upon running again, it runs without issue. I'm trying to find a way to efficiently build this to my liking. I've tried closing the database and re-opening in a nested function, but this doesn't seem to work either. Any suggestions?

Thank you !

Comment: `count` is a SQL key word.  Don't use it as a column name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the tip

Comment: `... EXISTS table(\`count\` integer ...`

Comment: @GordonLinoff `count` is not one of the [keywords](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); it's just the name of a function.